# What is my expectation in a lottery?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

There are 10 tickets in a lottery. I have two of them. The prizes are 10,5,2 dollars . 
Two of my friends X and Y come to me and say that I won.

Probability that X is saying true is 3/4 and Y if saying true is 1/3.

What is my expectation. (I would love a detailed explanation on dealing with my friends)

Attempt: My probability of winning is 1/5 so if my friends don't say anything then my expectation is 17/5  . I thought that X is more trustable so I can rely totally on him but I am confused there.

Comment: What do you mean by "probability that x is saying true"? Is this the probability that x tells the truth?

Comment: X either says true or false . true is of 3/4 probability. He maybe joking

Comment: would your friends tell you that you hadn't won if you actually had?

Comment: aside from that, your expectation before accounting for friends is not 17/5. you may have forgotten to divide the sum of the prizes by the number of prizes. I assume the prizes cannot be won twice either.

Comment: For first comment - yes. Second - You maybe right, can u give some details of how to do that ?

Comment: Can u post as an answer

Comment: We have to assume that the two friends act independently.

Comment: posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

your chances of having won are thus 5/6, because the probability that both are liars is $\frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$, so there is a $\frac{5}{6}$ chance that you have really won.

we now know that at least one of your tickets is a winner; the expectation from the first is 17/3.  The second may have won, with probability 1/9. It's expectation is again 17/3(I think) so your total expectation is

$\frac{5}{6}\frac{17}{3} + \frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{9}\frac{17}{3}$

Comment: Why didn't we took that X is speaking for prize of 10,5 or 2 and Y for 10,5 or 2 . also why didn't we calculate winning chance as $\frac{1}{3} x \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: because your chance of winning isn't the chance that both friends tell you you have won, because if one lies and one tells the truth, you may have still won. the only case in which you have not won is if both friends are lying.

Comment: the 17/3 accounts for the possible prizes. 10+5+2 = 17, and there are three prizes so we taje 17/3.